# Create mobile site with same content just different theme

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, mobile

I have a wordpress site and want to create a different theme for mobile.  I'd like to create a subdomain such as m.domain.com which will use a mobile optimized theme much different than the desktop version theme.  I understand multisite will handle the subdomain problem but I want all the content, custom posts, plugins, etc to be in a single site in the admin.

Is there anything out there that will allow me to create a mobile subdomain and have a separate theme applied to that subdomained site while keeping the content, posts, plugins in a single site in the admin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to read this useful article: http://digwp.com/2009/12/redirect-mobile-users-to-mobile-theme/

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress Mobile pack plugin does the exact job you want 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/

- you can choose different theme for mobile users
- you are provided with some specially made for phones themes to choose from
- no hassle - no bugs

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend [WPTouch](http://www.bravenewcode.com/wptouch/) which now has great iPhone, iPad and Android support. There is a basic free version but I would recommend the paid version which is only $39 and has a lot more features. You can then customize the look and feel.

Answer (score -1):

i am used best solution for this problem. Just create an subdomain like 'm.site.com' and copy main site all files and folder in 'm' directory....

And see your subdomain has been created with same content...

I am used this method....

Comment: Hello "used this method", be so kind as to explain the process more thoroughly. How about the database, for instance?